# How to create a user profile when creating a new user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django 1.7.4 as the server for my angular application. I needed to store more data for a user so I added a `UserProfile` model.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I would like to test and see how this works from the shell.

How can I create a user profile while creating a user?

I tried:

```
>>> u = User.objects.create(username="testing123", email="testing123@gmail.com")
>>> u.userprofile.create(company_name="onetwo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/bhaarat/.virtualenvs/djangorest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 428, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the related object, while it does not exist when you would do `u.userprofile`

Try it the same way you are creating the `User` object instead:

```
UserProfile.objects.create(user=u, company_name="onetwo")
```

Comment: I get the error `NameError: name 'UserProfile' is not defined` I think its because `UserProfile` isn't imported. How can I import it? I tried `from demo import UserProfile` but still get error `cannot import name UserProfile`

Comment: just like you import `User`, you need to import UserProfile, or python would not know what model you are refering to.

Comment: yeah...I can't seem to find out how to import it. I tried `from <myappname> import UserProfile` but that does not work.

Comment: please read up on basics of django - you should be doing `from <myappname>.models import UserProfile`